# how to say "The tree covers one fourth OF IT"

Tags: pronoms

How do I say the sentence in the title in French?

L'arbre couvre un quart ??? d'en ?

instead of:

L'arbre couvre un quart de l'image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> L'arbre **en** couvre un quart.

When "of it" refers to a part of something it'll often be "en". Don't forget that you will sometimes need to rearrange the sentence.

Comment: Also *L'arbre en couvre le quart.* and *L'arbre en occupe le quart.*

Comment: @Frank [also](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/also)

Comment: @jlliagre - ah ok :-)